# error : "Home/files" unexpected in Bash/ksh programme

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Getting error in `if` clause which says:

```
/home/files unexpected.
```

I do not know what is wrong, here's the KornShell (ksh) script.

```
#!/bin/ksh
selectPart="SELECT."
filePart="_FILE"
while read -r indxFile; do
  while read -r cobolFile; do
    query=$selectPart"${indxFile}"$filePart
    if [[ find /home/files  -name "${cobolFile}" | xargs grep $query ]];then
        while read -r scriptFile;do
          print "${scriptFile}"
        done < listScripts.txt > "${indxFile}".txt
    fi

  done < cobolNames.txt
done < indexedFiles.txt
```

Comment: You might want `>> "${indxFile}".txt`, as otherwise it will be overwritten by each inner while loop.

Comment: A condition is normally a command; the result depends on whether the command succeeds or fails. `[[` is a special case. The stuff between `[[` and `]]` is an expression, not a command.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the `[[ ]]` around the condition in your if:

```
if find /home/files  -name "${cobolFile}" | xargs grep $query ; then
```

Comment: Does this mean that the if clause will evaluate to true only if `$query` is present in `"${cobolFile}"

Comment: In at least one of the files named `$cobolFile`, yes

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details of your task. Here is updates to your code in question.

```
#!/bin/ksh
selectPart="SELECT."
filePart="_FILE"
while read -r indxFile; do
  while read -r cobolFile; do
    query=$selectPart"${indxFile}"$filePart
    findResult=find /home/files -name "${cobolFile}" | xargs grep $query
    echo "findResult: ${findResult}"
    if  [[${findResult} -eq 0]]; then
        while read -r scriptFile;do
          print "${scriptFile}"
        done < listScripts.txt >> "${indxFile}".txt
    fi
    done < cobolNames.txt
done < indexedFiles.txt
```